# Does desire to have sex comes under Sat, Rajas or Tamas?

Tags: gunas

Does desire to have sex comes under which guna?

If it comes under Rajas or Tamas then some food habits should vanish this desire to have sex.

If it is common across all 3 gunas then how come a person in Sat guna can get moksha? ( A person should not have any desires to get moksha as per my understanding)

Is Sat guna also not perfect? Is there something better than that in that case?

Edit:
Let me explain background of asking this question to get better answers

One of my collegues who is a brahman and wont eat non veg food ( which reduces Rajas and Tamas gunas if not eaten non veg food) and is so soft with others and wont involve in to unnecessary quarral with others then I assumed he might be the Sat guna person.

Recently he had a baby girl then this question aroused how come a Sat guna person have any desire. If Sat guna is most eligible condition for moksha, then how come a Sat guna person have any desires?

Even Gods will send woman to distract meditation (Tapas) of Rakshasas on supreme God to avoid asking boons

Comment: Sat is also not perfect. Beyond sat is that which is beyond everything, unaffected by all the gunas. Yasmin sattvarajastamasah sarve na vidyante. That is the supreme Brahman.

Comment: Besides Mr. Ross’ answer you can also have a look at this: Proneness to undertake work, impatience, commission of improper acts, constant **addiction to sensual objects** are the characteristics of the quality of ‘Rajas.’—(32)

Answer (score 2):

According to Manu it comes under Tamo Guna.

> Manu Smriti 12.38. **The craving after sensual pleasures is declared
> to be the mark of Darkness,** (the pursuit of) wealth (the mark) of
> Activity, (the desire to gain) spiritual merit the mark of Goodness;
> each later) named quality is) better than the preceding one.

Here, Tamas is mentioned as Darkness, Rajas as Activity and Sattva as Goodness.

Comment: Most of the persons who ever all have children because of this desire to have sex are all with Tamas guna, am I correct?

Comment: Yes ... some think that Tamas is bad but without Tamas we will all have insomnia. So you can understand. All Gunas play their roles in proper functioning of the universe. Without all Gunas participation proper functioning of the creation is not possible. @user2225190